# Detecting incorrect nesting of XML tags in Python

Tags: python, xml, nested

A question about testing proper nesting of XML tags:

I got a list of tags, extracted from top to bottom from an xml file:

1. Closing tags are clearly indicated by forward slash
2. /to and /lastname tags are incorrectly nested. They should be switched. /lastname should be within to, /to parent tags.

tag_list = ['note', 'to', 'firstname', '/firstname', 'lastname', '/to', '/lastname', '/note']

What would be the code or direction to spot that /lastname tag is outside of its parent which is to, /to pair?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an empty stack.

- Iterating through the list:

  - if you find a start tag, push it onto the stack.
  - if you find an end tag, compare it to the entry on top of the stack.

    - if the stack is empty or the top doesn't match, fail.
    - if it matches, pop the stack and continue.
- At the end of the iteration:

  - if the stack is empty, declare success.
  - otherwise fail.

Comment: Excellent. It seems to work for multiple tags with the same name. I have used similar algorithm before but on tags without slashes.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the backslashes, iterate on the  [reversed](https://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/whatsnew/node7.html) version, and compare with the original.

E.g., this will give you the indices of discrepancy:

```
wo = [tag[1: ] if tag and tag[0] == '/' else tag for tag in taglist]
rev = list(reversed(wo))
discrepancies = [i for i in xrange(len(wo)) if wo[i] != rev[i]]
```

Comment: Thank you. It answers the question related to the list of tags I posted. But it's not scalable to other tag orders, for example where tags are not placed symmetrically. ado you have solution for this? Here: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <b>
     <a>
         <hello>
          <doc>
          </doc>
         </hello>
  </a>
 </b>
 <e>
     <f>
         <hello>
          <doc>
          </doc>
         </hello>
  </f>
 </e>
</doc>